# Difference of two dataframes in python

Tags: python

I have a two dataframes
ex:

```
test_1
name1 name2
a1     b1
a1     b2
a2     b1
a2     b2
a2     b3
```

```
test_2
name1 name2
a1     b1
a1     b2
a2     b1
```

I need the difference of two dataframes like

```
name1 name2
a2     b2
a2     b3
```

Comment: Welcome Rohith! SO isn't a code writing service, but we're glad to help.  If this is a pandas or numpy question, you'll want to add that tag. I'd also check out the FAQ for how to write [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

df=pd.concat([a,b])

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))

idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]

df1=df.reindex(idx)